# Can't add Forecast/Quota report to Managed Package

Tags: reporting, isv, sales-cloud, 2gp, forecast

I want to add a report and dashboard to my 2GP package, which visualizes Opportunity [Forecasts and Quota](https://www.salesforce.com/resources/articles/building-a-sales-forecast-guide/). I know that not all orgs have this feature enabled.

When I try to package a **Report Type** using:

```
<sections>
    <columns>
        <checkedByDefault>false</checkedByDefault>
        <field>Id</field>
        <table>ForecastingItem</table>
    </columns>
    <columns>
        <checkedByDefault>false</checkedByDefault>
        <field>ForecastingItemCategory</field>
        <table>ForecastingItem</table>
    </columns>
```

from a scratch org that has Forecasting enabled

```
{
  "orgName": "Forecast",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi"],
  "settings": {
    "forecastingSettings": {
      "enableForecasts": true
    }
  }
}
```

it fails with

> In field: baseObject - no CustomObject named ForecastingItem found

**Is it possible to package related artifacts, and how do they behave in subscriber orgs with Forecasting disabled?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could solve it by two changes:

We forgot to **enforce our Scratch org definition** file during package version creation

```
sfdx force:package:version:create ... -f config/project-scratch-def.json
```

...and we **missed `quoteSettings`** in the `project-scratch-def.json`

```
"settings": {
    "forecastingSettings": {
        "enableForecasts": true
    },
    "quoteSettings": {
        "enableQuote": true
    }
}
```